# Android - Resource Configurations Not Working

Tags: android, layout, tablet, android-resources

I am currently trying to update my layout for multiple screen sizes. I am attempting to set the left margin of a button. I have the button set to the proper @dimens resource. When I change the value in the values/dimens.xml the button margin changes.

However, when loading the nexus 9 in the emulator or genymotion emulator they will NOT use the values-sw720dp version of the dimension.

My values folder

```
values/
    values-sw720dp/
        dimens.xml
attrs.xml
colors.xml
dimens.xml
etc..
```

I can not figure out why it will not read these values.
I am testing it on 5.0 lolipop, and the min android level is 13.

I have double checked the resource is named correctly.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values-sw720dp/` folder should be at the same level as the `values/` folder, not below it. Your folder hierarchy should look like this:

```
res/
    values/
        attrs.xml
        colors.xml
        dimens.xml
    values-sw720dp/
        dimens.xml
```

Also, make sure that the emulator is matching the `-sw720dp` resource qualifier. You can check this by putting a string (or something else easily recognizable) with a different value in each resource folder, and print it as a diagnostic.

Comment: I thought I had already tried that, but it seems I hadn't. Thanks ted! you rock! I will accept the answer in 7 minutes. Thanks again.